# Passing application object to controllers in LoopBack 4

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

In the LoopBack 3 docs, it was possible to pass the application object in `[model].app` (e.g. `Book.app`).

How can I access the application object in the same way in LoopBack 4?

I'm trying to dynamically (at runtime) create a controller from another controller:

```js
app.controller(BookController);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use constructor dependency injection on any class that's binded to the lb4 app:

```js
constructor(
    @inject(CoreBindings.APPLICATION_INSTANCE) app: Application,
) {}
```

---

### Further reference

- [Binding key API reference](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.core.corebindings.application_instance.html)
- [Identical GitHub issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5995)